# A good guide for brand new EVE online players?

Tags: eve-online

Just started playing with my brother and we both are brand spanking new to the game. Just wondering if there was any experts out there that have any helpful links or tips. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hook up with a corporation called EVE University. They have been around forever and help new players with learning EVE. That one bears repeating: JOIN EVE UNIVERSITY.

Go through the tutorials.

Starting out specialize--you aren't going to be able to effectively fly all the ships a vet can soon, but if you focus you can get 90-95% effective in relatively short periods of time.

Get into a corp. EVE is a fun, but huge and directionless game. A corp will help you define your goals and keep you interested in playing.

EVE U, though I think is the biggest one.

Don't fly what you can't afford to replace.

And EVE has some of the highest highs and lowest lows you will feel in a game--and much like real life--there can be lots of awaiting in between.

EVE is not a game for fair fights.

Comment: Those are really good tips there sir, I have played for a solid 6 hours and I hit one of those lows you referred to. /sadface. I have another month to give it another try but really it makes me want to return to the WoW addiction. I'm going to try and give it some space and then hit up your tips and see if they light the fire once again. 

Also, fair fights REALLY don't exist and I think that is what really bothers me. But I wont delete this yet. Thank you.

Comment: Of course fair fights exist in EVE, but only when you've got the biggest guns! If there's one thing I learnt playing EVE it's to never bring a knife to a gunfight. Having said that, there's very little more fun than being the stinging mosquito in an Assault Ship wearing down capital ships that can't touch your speed or manoeuvring!

Comment: If there is a fair fight in EVE at least one of the Fleet Commanders (FCs), if not both FCs screwed up.  EVE is a more darwinistic and less forgiving game than WOW, but for that it is a much more intense game and fosters stronger bonds between the players. Its radically different than WOW. Give it time and get into a corp (an active one) to give it direction and support and structure. And when I am flying a 250M ISK PVP ship, I am not looking for fair fights--I want to come home with my ship--and not have it be a coin toss.

Comment: Question - what do you get *out* of EVE University? PvP experience? Combat theory and practice? Economic skills? Thinking about signing up to it - on my third account reactivation now and really want to stick it out this time! :)

Comment: Eve University has all of that and more. They have scheduled classes online, with a teacher on TeamSpeak. A community of teachers and students who are always available to help with whatever question you have.

Answer (score 5):

You could have a look a the Industrial Sized Knowledge Gide, aka ISK guide, which can be found [here](http://www.isktheguide.com/). You'll find there a lot of good tips about almost anything you can do in Eve.

Comment: Worth noting, is that there is a new version of this guide, which is recommended reading to anyone new to the game, or even old people who wish to expand into areas they haven't played much with.